# C# 2012 List Object limits

Tags: c#, sql-server, list, visual-studio-2012

I have a chunk of code I know can be done better, I just am not sure how to go about it. I think there are some methods that can help with this but I am not sure so please forgive me if this is elemental programming.

I am iterating through a a DataReader to populate a List of objects, but I want to limit the number of indexes in the list. My current code looks like this:

```
while (dr.Read())
{
    temp.Add(new Object()
        {
            PropertyA = dr.GetString(0),
            ...
            ...
        });
}

if (temp.Count > 100)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        retObject.Add(new Object()
            {
                PropertyA = temp[i].PropertyA,
                ...
                ...
             });
    }

    return retObject;
}
else
{
    return temp;
}
```

This essentially loops twice over a data set ... So, without sounding TOO much like a Novice programmer here, what would be the best way to limit the result set to 100 WITHOUT using TOP(###) in the Query itself? (We use Stored Procs so changing the Query is out of the question).

Thank folks! I look forward to your answers.

Comment: Do you have any issues using a counter in the `dr.Read()` loop?

Comment: probabaly just `return temp.GetRange(0,100)`

Comment: BTW - your current code will return 101 items - is that desired?

Comment: GetRange worked beautifully! Thank you very much!

Comment: Well ... yeah 101 items was ok ... But the GetRange does exactly what I need so that was the answer. Thank you MadScienceDreams!

Comment: @EricOlson Realize that GetRange is effectively doing an entire loop/copy internally, just like yours, so it's not really more efficient... My option (below) doesn't ever read and create the data...

Answer (score 3):

In your first loop, just keep a counter:

```
int found = 0;
while (dr.Read() && found < 100)
{
    ++found;
    retObject.Add(new Object() // No need for "temp" anymore
    {
        PropertyA = dr.GetString(0),
        ...
        ...
    });
}

return retObject;
```